# update fields in MySQL based on condition

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have two tables, one accounts( login, password, coin, hwid) and one block_list(id, hwid).  I want to check if accounts.hwid match with block_list.hwid, if yes then set on each account.hwid + 500 coin.

I use the above query for this :

```
UPDATE accounts SET coin=500  WHERE hwid IN (SELECT hwid FROM block_list)
```

This query works, but there are even 6 accounts with same hwid, i want to set +500 coins only on one account with hwid in block_list.

How i can limit updating of coins to one account with same hwid as in block_list?

So, i have 10 accounts with same hwid. I want to compare account.hwid with block_list.hwid and update just one account from account.sql with same hwid.

Example :
In account tabel exist 10 accounts named admin and hwid 102012
In block_list exist only one hwid 102012

This query :

```
UPDATE accounts SET coin=500  WHERE hwid IN (SELECT hwid FROM block_list)
```

Will update all 10 accounts from accounts

I want to update just one account, I want to set coins + 500 more just on one account.. other 9 shoule be ignore..

Tried all ways, some help?

Comment: You can only do that if you can uniquely identify that row. Do you have some primary key in your table?

Comment: Can't account.hwid can be treat as a unique key ?

Comment: If it is repeatitive you cant define it unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what is your problem, But syntatically, this should work.

```
UPDATE accounts SET coin = coin+500  WHERE hwid = (SELECT hwid FROM block_list LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: its not what you wrote. it is what you have updated.

Comment: Not work, after run query all 6 accounts added +500 coins,not just one

Comment: What are your primary keys and foreign keys?

Comment: Your problem is from design phase, you cant fix in implementation phase. Update question with a context. Explain what you wanted to do in actual.